# .htaccess, how can I remove pattern from url?

Tags: ajax, .htaccess

I would like to clean my urls from this:

```
https://example.com/track&id=180
```

to:

```
https://example.com/track/180
```

My code is as follow:

My `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^welcome/([^/]+)/?$                index.php?a=welcome&filter=$1   [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^track/([^/]+)/?$                  index.php?a=track&filter=$1     [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+)+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$ index.php?a=$1&q=$3             [L,QSA]
```

But if I use the 2nd example (the url without `&id=`) **via Ajax it returns "undefined".**

I tried the Ajax call with this link button

```
<a href="'.$this->url.'/track/'.$id.'" rel="loadpage">Click Here</a>
```

I supposed it's undefined because in my requests I get the `id` parameter in PHP as `$_GET['id'];`.

**So my question is: why it doesn't work on Ajax?**

Here is my `functions.js`

```
$(function() {
    $("body").on("click", "a[rel='loadpage']", function(e) {
        // Get the link location that was clicked
        startLoadingBar();
        pageurl = $(this).attr('href');
        // Replace the path of the url from index to the path with raw content
        var custom = pageurl;
        var custom = custom.replace(baseUrl+'/track', 'page.php?a=track');
        var custom = custom.replace(baseUrl+'/', 'page.php?a=welcome');
        // Request the page
        $.ajax({url:custom,success: function(data) {
            // Show the content
            $('#content').html(data);
            // Stop the loading bar
            stopLoadingBar();
            // Scroll the document at the top of the page
            $(document).scrollTop(0);
            // Reload functions
            selectExplore();
            reload();
        }});


        // Store the url to the last page accessed
        if(pageurl != window.location){
            window.history.pushState({path:pageurl}, '', pageurl);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

`.htaccess` isn't my forte, so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the problem is only with Ajax

Comment: Does the rewritten URL work if you just put it in the browser vs using ajax?

Comment: @PanamaJack yes, if I go directly to `https://example.com/track/180` everything works fine.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the network request and response in Chrome development tools network tab? You need to look at what it's sending to your server and what the response is during the ajax call.

Comment: @anubhava custom is `page.php?a=track/184`

Comment: Is that a valid URL for AJAX call? I thought AJAX is using `/track/184`

Comment: @anubhava inside `page.php` a is set like: `if(isset($_GET['a']) && isset($action[$_GET['a']])) {
 $page_name = $action[$_GET['a']];
} else {
 $page_name = 'welcome';
}`

Comment: @anubhava indeed it's not valid, `page.php?a=track&id=184` is valid, so how can I proceed?

Comment: This seems to be Javascript issue, what are values of `pageurl` and `baseUrl`

Comment: @anubhava baseurl: `https://example.com` and pageurl:`https://example.com/track/184`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this JS code to send your AJAX call:

```
var custom = pageurl.replace(baseUrl+'/track/', '/page.php?a=track&id=');

// Request the page
$.ajax({url:custom,success: function(data) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, I just changed this: `var custom = pageurl.replace(baseUrl+'/track/', 'page.php?a=track&id=');` just in case you are not in root folder.